# How to use two themes in asp.net mvc project

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have two themes' folders called Default and New in Views folder. These folders are included .cshtml extension files. I want to use these folders as theme option. How can I do theme settings in global.asax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install bootstrap through visual studio **Manage Nugget Packages** and you can utilize free themes available. Lot of free themes are available in https://bootswatch.com/. Download a CSS from the mentioned link and replace the one in your bootstrap CSS folder. Hope this helps...

**EDIT**

Actually in Asp.Net MVC Global.asax has nothing to do with setting themes. Current theme in MVC is decided by the styles specified in _Layout.cshtml file. Usually this file lies inside Views\Shared path. The _ViewStart.cshtml which lies directly under Views folder decides which layout should the view use.

**Approach 1**

If we require some other layout for certain views we can add another _ViewStart.cshtml inside the folder where those views exist and specify the path of _NewLayout.cshtml in it. The views will automatically get the new layout/theme while you render it.

**Approach 2**

Use a logic and set your layout/theme accordingly as shown below in /Views/_ViewStart.cshtml file,

```
@{
   if (this.User.IsInRole("Admin") || !this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
      Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
   } else {
      Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutUser.cshtml";
   }
 }
```

Comment: I have to use Default and New folders, because I have  special files for each two themes. For this reason, I need to do some settings in global.asax.